# WSO2 API Manager 1.4.0, Error generating Application Key

Tags: wso2, key, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I downloaded API Manager (1.4.0) this morning and i launched it like version 1.3.1,
I can create, publish and subscribe APIs perfectly.

My problem is when I try to generate my Application Key (from Store, My Subscriptions) : 
["Generate" Capture](http://imageshack.us/a/img259/4368/cran12062013171652.png)

---

**Keys are not generated**. I'm asked to wait but keys never appear. (the same append for Sandbox keys)
["Please wait" Capture](http://imageshack.us/a/img15/5425/cran12062013171708.png)

---

I did exactly the same thing i did for the 1.3.1 version (and it was working), is there anything else or something different to do ?

---

### The errors :

In my terminal I have the following errors but even looking for them on internet i don't understand the problem :

```
ERROR - RhinoEngine org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of null (/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag#129)              
ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: 
TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of null (/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag#129)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of null (/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag#129)

        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:446)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:191)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:269)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of null (/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag#129)        

        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3582)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3601)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2160)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:129)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:57)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:441)
        ... 24 more

[2013-06-12 17:17:05,716] ERROR - RhinoEngine org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "h1" from undefined (/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/errors/template.jag#18)
[2013-06-12 17:17:05,716] ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "h1" from undefined (/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/errors/template.jag#18)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "h1" from undefined (/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/errors/template.jag#18)         

        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:446)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:191)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:269)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "h1" from undefined (/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/errors/template.jag#18)        

        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3582)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3595)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1381)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.fancy.templates.errors.c0._c1(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/errors/template.jag:18)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.fancy.templates.errors.c0.call(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/errors/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c24(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:163)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c40(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:462)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.fancy.templates.layout.base.c0._c1(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/layout/base/template.jag:28)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.fancy.templates.layout.base.c0.call(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/layout/base/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c24(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:163)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c40(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:459)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.fancy.templates.page.base.c0._c1(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/page/base/template.jag:93)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.fancy.templates.page.base.c0.call(/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/page/base/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c38(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:442)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.error_pages.c0._c1(/store/site/pages/error-pages/500.jag:7)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.error_pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/error-pages/500.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:57)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.error_pages.c0._c0(/store/site/pages/error-pages/500.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.error_pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/error-pages/500.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.error_pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/error-pages/500.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.error_pages.c0.exec(/store/site/pages/error-pages/500.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:441)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Can you share the environement information (Operating system, Browser) which you are running API Manager?

Comment: I'm using Linux (I tried it on Ubuntu releases 11.10 and 12.04.1) and Mozilla Firefox (version 20.0)

Comment: It's finally working, I cancelled the subscription and subcribe again and clearde my browser cache and the I tried and it was working